# Android Preferences String Not Working in Activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Okay, I am super frustrated at this point, I have anther file which I have set up exactly the same, but for some reason this just doesn't want to work. I have a PreferenceScreen xml file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference 
        android:summary="@string/alias_summary" 
        android:key="alias" 
        android:title="@string/alias_title"/>
     <EditTextPreference 
        android:summary="@string/server_url_summary" 
        android:key="server_url" 
        android:title="@string/server_url_title" 
        android:defaultValue="http://www.myserverhere.com"/>

    <ListPreference 
         android:summary="@string/main_bg_list_pref_summary"
         android:title="@string/main_bg_list_pref_title" 
         android:key="main_view_bg_list_pref"
         android:entries="@array/color_names"
         android:entryValues="@array/color_values"
         android:defaultValue="white"/>
    <EditTextPreference />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

when I try and call the server url (sorry I had to remove the actual link, but it is exactly the same none-the-less) in my activity, it just won't display but if I hardocde that server url, it works like a charm. I have no idea why it will not see that pref.. any help would be greatly appreciated!!

here is my activity code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.graphics.Color;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReviewsByCategory  extends ListActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> reviews = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    View linearLayoutCustomList;
    private final static String TAG = "ReviewsByCategory";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.remote_list);


        linearLayoutCustomList = findViewById(R.id.customList);

        displayReviews();
    }

    private void displayReviews() 
    {
        String[] fields = new String[]{"date", "description", "addinfo", "review", "rating", "alias"};
        int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.date, R.id.description, R.id.addInfo, R.id.review, R.id.rating, R.id.alias};
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, reviews, R.layout.remote_row, fields, ids);

         Log.d(TAG, "just before populate list");
        populateList();
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void populateList() 
    {

        BufferedReader in = null;

        try
        {
            String category = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CATEGORY");
            category = "?CATEGORY=" + category;
            //THIS WILL NOT WORK
            //String server = prefs.getString("server_url", "http://www.myserverhere.com" + category);
            //THIS WILL WORK
            String server = "http://www.myserverhere.com" + category;

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(server));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";

            while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp.put("date", line);

                if((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    temp.put("description", line);
                }
                if((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    temp.put("addinfo", line);
                }
                if((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    temp.put("review", line);
                }
                if((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    temp.put("rating", line);
                }
                if((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    temp.put("alias", line);
                }
                reviews.add(temp);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String arg1) 
    {
        linearLayoutCustomList = findViewById(R.id.customList);
        String bg = prefs.getString("custom_list_bg_color", "#000000");
        linearLayoutCustomList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bg));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a breakpoint and debug your app. That will tell you what's happening.

Comment: Assuming it's getting the server_url ok, it's not getting the category. You're only adding the category if the server_url is not found.

Comment: I concatenated the category to the url in both instances

Comment: No, you didn't. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: It's still giving a NullPointerException

Comment: Did you initialize `prefs` with the `getSharedPreferences(String, int)` method? I don't see it in the code you given.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's getting the server_url ok, it's not getting the category. You're only adding the category if the server_url is not found.

In other words, instead of

```
String server = 
prefs.getString("server_url", "http://www.myserverhere.com" + category);
```

You should write

```
String server = 
prefs.getString("server_url", "http://www.myserverhere.com") + category;
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked fine after I added this line:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```